# Snap-ins Offline support

Tags: liveagent, snap-ins

When the offline support is active in snap-ins setup and the user fill up the prechat form and finally click on submit, the message get displayed that case is created but in actual when I checked in the org, case is not getting created. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to verify object level access ...also verify if any required field is not given in form......

Comment: Please check that web-to-case is active in your org or not? If not then please active it and then test it!